# ansible set_fact to the list with jinja2 condition

Tags: ansible

I'd like to set a `common_apt_packages` list based on OS distribution, so I've used jinja2 if condition as the script below, but the return `common_apt_packages` type is `AnsibleUnsafeText`

```yaml
- hosts: localhost
  vars:
    common_apt_packages_ubuntu_22_04:
    - ack-grep
    - acl
    - apt-transport-https
    - build-essential
    - dstat
    - git-core
    - htop
    - iftop
    - iotop
  tasks:
    - name: Set common_apt_packages for ubuntu {{ ansible_distribution_version }}
      set_fact:
        common_apt_packages: "{% if ansible_distribution_version =='22.04' %} {{ common_apt_packages_ubuntu_22_04 }} {% else %} {{ common_apt_packages_ubuntu_18_04 }} {% endif %}"
```

How can I improve the script to return `common_apt_packages` as a List variable?

Comment: Just remove the spaces between the Jinja statements in the last line of your code.

Answer (score 1):

Just remove the white spaces between `%} {{` and `}} {%`, because Ansible will then handle it as a string, not as a list.
With `type_debug` you can get the output type.

```yaml
- hosts: localhost
  vars:
    common_apt_packages_ubuntu_22_04:
    - ack-grep
    - acl
    common_apt_packages_ubuntu_18_04:
    - vim
    - nano
  tasks:
    - name: Set common_apt_packages for ubuntu {{ ansible_distribution_version }}
      set_fact:
        common_apt_packages_without_spaces: "{% if ansible_distribution_version =='22.04' %}{{ common_apt_packages_ubuntu_22_04 }}{% else %}{{ common_apt_packages_ubuntu_18_04 }}{% endif %}"

    - name: Set common_apt_packages for ubuntu {{ ansible_distribution_version }}
      set_fact:
        common_apt_packages_with_spaces: "{% if ansible_distribution_version =='22.04' %} {{ common_apt_packages_ubuntu_22_04 }} {% else %} {{ common_apt_packages_ubuntu_18_04 }} {% endif %}"

    - debug:
        msg: "{{ common_apt_packages_without_spaces }} ==> {{ common_apt_packages_without_spaces | type_debug }}"

    - debug:
        msg: "{{ common_apt_packages_with_spaces }} ==> {{ common_apt_packages_with_spaces | type_debug }}"
```

```yaml
TASK [Set common_apt_packages for ubuntu 20.04] ************
ok: [localhost]

TASK [debug] ***********************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": "['vim', 'nano'] ==> list"
}

TASK [debug] ***********************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": " ['vim', 'nano']  ==> AnsibleUnsafeText"
}
```

When you try to install them using the apt module:

```yaml
# without white spaces
"package": [
                "vim",
                "nano"
            ]
```

```yaml
# with white spaces
"package": [
                " ['vim'",
                " 'nano'] "
            ]
"msg": "No package(s) matching '['vim'' available"
```

Answer (score 1):

Create the lists. For example in *group_vars*

```yaml
shell> cat group_vars/all/packages.yml
list_of_packages_for_18_04: [pkg1_18_04, pkg2_18_04, pkg3_18_04]
list_of_packages_for_20_04: [pkg1_20_04, pkg2_20_04, pkg3_20_04]
list_of_packages_for_22_04: [pkg1_22_04, pkg2_22_04, pkg3_22_04]
default_list_of_packages: [pkg1, pkg2, pkg3]
```

and put the lists of the packages into a dictionary. For example,

```yaml
- hosts: localhost
  vars:
    packages:
      '18.04': "{{ list_of_packages_for_18_04 }}"
      '20.04': "{{ list_of_packages_for_20_04 }}"
      '22.04': "{{ list_of_packages_for_22_04 }}"
      'default': "{{ default_list_of_packages }}"
    my_packages: "{{ packages[ansible_distribution_version]|
                     default(packages.default) }}"
  tasks:
    - debug:
        var: ansible_distribution_version
    - debug:
        var: my_packages
```

gives (abridged)

```yaml
TASK [debug] ******************************************************
ok: [localhost] => 
  ansible_distribution_version: '20.04'

TASK [debug] ******************************************************
ok: [localhost] => 
my_packages:
  - pkg1_20_04
  - pkg2_20_04
  - pkg3_20_04
```

---

Your problem is that output of Jinja is always a string. Ansible should convert it automatically if it is a valid YAML. If you for whatever reason have to use Jinja create the string first and convert it to YAML explicitly. For example,

```yaml
    - set_fact:
        packages_str: |
          {% if ansible_distribution_version == '22.04' %}
          {{ common_apt_packages_ubuntu_22_04 }}
          {% else %}
          {{ common_apt_packages_ubuntu_18_04 }}
          {% endif %}"
    - set_fact:
        packages: "{{ packages_str|from_yaml }}"
```

You can't put the declarations into a single *set_fact* because the second declaration knows nothing about the first one. But, you can put them into any *vars*, of course.

---

Test of the conversion in Ansible 2.12.9 Python 3.8.5, and Jinja 3.0.1

```yaml
- hosts: localhost
  vars:
    packages_str: |
          {% if ansible_distribution_version == '20.04' %}
          {{ list_of_packages_for_20_04 }}
          {% else %}
          {{ list_of_packages_for_18_04 }}
          {% endif %}
    packages: "{{ packages_str|from_yaml }}"

  tasks:
    - debug:
        var: ansible_distribution_version
    - debug:
        var: packages_str|type_debug
    - debug:
        var: packages|type_debug
    - debug:
        var: packages_str
    - debug:
        var: packages
```

gives (abridged)

```yaml
TASK [debug] **************************************************
ok: [localhost] => 
  ansible_distribution_version: '20.04'

TASK [debug] **************************************************
ok: [localhost] => 
  packages_str|type_debug: list

TASK [debug] **************************************************
ok: [localhost] => 
  packages|type_debug: list

TASK [debug] **************************************************
ok: [localhost] => 
  packages_str:
  - pkg1_20_04
  - pkg2_20_04
  - pkg3_20_04

TASK [debug] **************************************************
ok: [localhost] => 
  packages:
  - pkg1_20_04
  - pkg2_20_04
  - pkg3_20_04
```